# Why does Kotlin documentation for ArrayList mention JavaScript?

Tags: kotlin

In the documentation for ArrayList it says:

> Provides a MutableList implementation, which uses a resizable array as its backing storage.
>
> This implementation doesn't provide a way to manage capacity, as backing JS array is resizeable itself. There is no speed advantage to pre-allocating array sizes in JavaScript, so this implementation does not include any of the capacity and "growth increment" concepts.

Link here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/

Why does the documentation reference JavaScript here? My understanding is Kotlin is based on the JVM and Java. Interested to know what role JS plays here.

Comment: Kotlin can be compiled (or transpiled, if you prefer) to JavaScript ([doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-overview.html)) in addition to compiling to JVM bytecode and [native](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-overview.html) code.

Comment: If you do not want JS related stuff toggle the JS bubble at the top of the site.

Comment: Also the little dots next to each function etc indicate which platform they apply to. Most apply to the JVM (green, or cyan for the Common stuff that's part of everything) but you'll occasionally see something that only applies to the JS or Native platforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin is a multi-platform language. While it was primarily designed for compatibility with the JVM, it can compile to native code or JavaScript. These different targets have differences in their standard libraries.

At the top of their documentation pages, you can see toggles for the three target platforms which you can use to hide documentation for platforms you aren't interested in.

[image]

You'll notice there's an orange dot next to the documentation for the ArrayList class you mentioned. That is because this ArrayList class is only in the JavaScript standard library. On JVM, there's only a typealias to the JVM implementation of ArrayList, so there's a green dot next to that.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin can currently be compiled to JVM byte code, JS, and native machine code. The website shows details for all three targets. The part you are quoting is exclusively about the JS target.